# Best approach to use in multi-module Maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I have several modules:

```
A
B
C
```

and each module has a **core module** as one of its **dependencies**:

```
A+core
B+core
C+core
```

And now I'm supposed to package **A, B, C** together in **D** but I managed to **exclude core modules** from **B** and **C** and I kept the core module in **A**.

```
D 
|+ A-core
|+ B-removed core
|+ C-removed core
```

What is the best thing to do in this situation; is this a bad practise?

Comment: Is the `core` for each module A, B and C the same `core` module?

Comment: yes it is, should anything be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have more than one dependency that pulls the `core` dependency in `D` `pom.xml`
So, the exclusion is not required.
The important thing here is that `A`, `B` and `C` depends on exactly the same version of the `core` dependency otherwise the `D` packaging could include a version of `core` rather than another one. 
 It may compile without error, but generate exceptions at runtime if the use of these two versions are not compatible between them.

**So focus on using a unique version of `core` in `A`, `B`, `C`.**

Using a parent pom or creating a dependency aggregating common dependencies are tools to ease that.

Comment: You are welcome. It is possible. But generally, we associate the parent pom to all modules of a same application to inherit/enforce the dependencies/Java version/plugin configuration, etc...of the whole application. It makes the application build more consistent, concise and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Project layout:

```
 root
   +--- pom.xml
   +--- core
   !      +-- pom.xml
   +--- A
   !    +-- pom.xml
   +--- B
   !    +-- pom.xml
   +--- C
        +-- pom.xml
```

Using `core` as a dependency in other modules. The order of build is handled by Maven.